# Reading/Writing object Array to file

Tags: java

I am trying to save an array of objects to a file and then to be able to read the objects from that file and add them to an Array. I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure if my problem lies in my read or write methods.

```
Movie allmovies = new Movie[4]
public void writeFile()
    {
        try
        {
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("movies.txt");
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
           oos.writeObject(allmovies);
           oos.close();
           System.out.println("File Saved");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in output:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
    public void readFile()
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("movies.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Movie[] allmovies = (Movie[]) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();   
            System.out.println("File Imported");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in output:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Edit: Also the format of the example file we have been given that we need to read is

Movie Title:

Director:

fileSize:

duration:

I was able to get it to write 1 object and read 1 object but it was in a different format when I view the saved file. Is there anyway to get it in the same format as the example?

Comment: a) Your code doesn't "do anything" because.. you haven't written your code to do anything observable. No print statements that show anything, and you just read your movies into a **local** variable `allmovies` that you're not returning/printing, etc. (You also have a variable `allmovies` declared outside the methods but you're not reading into that - and in any case you're not printing it either). So.. maybe you haven't shown your real code, but the code above isn't expected to "do" anything.

Comment: "Also the format of the example file we have been given that we need to read is" .. and here you're showing a text-based file format. So if that's how you should be reading/writing, then you shouldn't be using object serialization.

Comment: Long story short: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I only posted the methods...

Answer (score 1):

> Also the format of the example file we have been given that we need to
>   read is
>
> Movie Title:
>
> Director:
>
> fileSize:
>
> duration:
>
> I was able to get it to write 1 object and read 1 object but it was in
>   a different format when I view the saved file.

Java serialization allows to encode an object to bytes and not to a textual  human understandable representation of the serialized object.
If you want really to write the file in the format you show, you should use :

- to write the movies in a textual representation : a `BufferedWriter` wrapping a `FileWriter`. 
  For example : `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myFile"))`.
  It has an `append(CharSequence)` method to append `String` objects and a `newLine()` method to append a newline.
- to read the movies in a textual representation : A `BufferedReader` wrapping a `FileReader`. 
  For example : `new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile"))`.
  It has a `readLine()` method to read a line of the stream.

---

If you want to serialize movies as bytes and only render them as a textual representation, keep the use of the Java serialization and add a processing to display the Movie array in the required textual format.
After deserializing the array, you just need to iterate on it to generate the required textual representation of the movie.
For example to render the read objects in the standard output, you could write :

```
Movie[] movies = (Movie[]) ois.readObject(); 
for (Movie movie : movies){
      System.out.println("Movie Title:" + movie.getTitle());
      System.out.println("Director:" + movie.getDirector());
      System.out.println("fileSize:" + String.valueOf(movie.getTitle()));
      System.out.println("duration:" + movie.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there some way I can pm you? I can't post the code I have now because it is too long. I have managed to get it saving just the names as String to a text file, but would like to save the entire object (name,director,fileSize,duration)

Answer (score 0):

This has been done using arrays without any collections. I modified your code a bit, hope this helps.You can directly copy this code and run. It will successfully read the objects and display all four of them. In a future version which I will upload I will add more commenting to increase the clarity for the same.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Test {
Movie[] allMovies = new Movie[4];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.allMovies[0] = new Movie("A","B",1L,2L);
    t.allMovies[1] = new Movie("C","D",1L,2L);
    t.allMovies[2] = new Movie("E","F",1L,2L);
    t.allMovies[3] = new Movie("G","H",1L,2L);
    t.writeFile();
    t.readFile();
}
public void writeFile()
{
    try
    {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("movies.txt");
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
       oos.writeObject(allMovies);
       oos.close();
       System.out.println("File Saved");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in output:" + e.toString());
    }
}
public void readFile()
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("movies.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Movie[] allmovies = (Movie[]) ois.readObject();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            System.out.println("Movie = " + allmovies[i].movieTitle + " Director = " + allmovies[i].director + " FileSize = " + allmovies[i].fileSize + " Duration = " + allmovies[i].duration);
        }
        ois.close();   
        System.out.println("File Imported");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in output:" + e.toString());
    }
}
}
class Movie implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1647631086810497694L;
String movieTitle;
String director;
Long fileSize;
Long duration;
Movie(String m, String d, Long fs, Long dur){
    this.movieTitle = m;
    this.director = d;
    this.fileSize = fs;
    this.duration = dur;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. The writeFile() works, but the readFile() prints what is in the file, but gives a null pointer exception, but it doesn't crash?

Comment: Could you share what exception it is throwing, I mean the stack trace because I ran the code without any issues.

Comment: "Error in output:java.lang.NullPointerException". I'm not sure its actually adding them to the array rather than just printing whats in the file. Also, I edited my original post to include that I would like it be in String format, not binary.

Comment: I think I know whats wrong here, can you change the name of the file from 'movies.txt' to something else such as 'newmovies.txt' and try running it? The name occurs at 2 places in the code, please make the change to both of them.

Comment: Same error, and when I go to view all the Movies in the array, it only shows the ones that I have added through my addMovie() method.

Comment: Ok, so you are using a custom addMovie method, in the code above, I have directly assigned 4 movies and printing them out. Can you run the code above without any change in a new java project and once it is successful, then you can add your code to it and check where exactly it fails. Or you can share your existing code what you are running(which is giving the exception) here.

Comment: I do not wish to save the file in binary format as I have posted above. Please stop suggesting this.